# Kubernetes Egress call restrict with namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, calico, kubernetes-networkpolicy, kubernetes-namespace

I have application running in K3s and want to implement network policy based on namespace only.

 Let's assume that currently I have three namespace A, B and C. I want to allow egress (external call to internet from pod) for `namespace-A` and remaining `namespace[B & C]` egress calls should be blocked/denied.
 Is this possible in Kubernetes network policy (and not calico or cilium) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `deny all egress` policy like described in [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-deny-all-egress-traffic):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-egress
  namespce: your-namespace
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

This policy will be applied to all pods in the namespace because the pod selector is empty and that means (quoting [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#networkpolicy-resource)):

> An empty podSelector selects all pods in the namespace.

The policy will block all egress traffic because it has `Egress` as policy type but it doesn't have any `egress` section.

If you want to allow in-cluster egress you might want to add an `egress` section in the policy, like for example:

```
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          networking/namespace: kube-system
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: kube-dns
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
```

This allows all traffic from the namespace where you create the network policy to pods labeled with `k8s-app: kube-dns` in namespace `kube-system` on port 53 (TCP and UDP).

Comment: @Whites11- I require the egress control based on namespace and not tcp/udp ports. Simply allow egress calls for NS-A and deny/block egress calls for NS-B & NS-C. Also I dont want to interrupt anything in Ingress calls.